# Is it possible to see favorite tags of another user?

Tags: support, tag-watching

Is it possible to access it of tags which were [favorited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/favorite-tags/info) by a specific user? (Similarly as list of [favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/favorites/info) are publicly accessible from the profile page.)

I am aware that for searching among favorites, both `infavorites:<userid>` and `infavorites:mine` can be used in search. However, when I tried changing `intags:mine` to `intags:<userid>`, the latter seems not to be working.

---

I asked this after a recent discussion with another user who saw a change in his favorite tags and was unaware of making the change himself. The resolution of that problem is that he probably made this by mistake or (more likely) that is was result of some tags being merged/synonymized. But still, after that discussion I was curious whether one user has a possibility to share his favorite tags with another user in some more comfortable way than taking a screenshot or typing/copypasting the list of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible for ordinary users. Favorite tags are part of personal preferences, which are not part of our public profile.

Moderators can see any user favorite tags though, as they can see private details, including the Preferences tab of any user's profile.

I agree it would be nice if we can have option to share or export the list, especially when one has lots of favorite tags, so until such option is added, you can write the following in console (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Chrome browser) to get a comma separated list of your favorite tags:

```
$("#interestingTags a").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(", ")
```

Just type the above while in the homepage of any site and the list will be displayed.